# How to reorder columns of a data.frame with na condition?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

My problem: a large dataset with columns containing very few values.

What I whish: reordering columns with sorting frequency of missing values condition.

What I tried:

```
 # my data.frame
 data <- data.frame(column1 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA),    # 4 NA
                    column2 = c(4, NA, NA, 1),   # 2 NA
                    column3 = c(12, NA, 5, 78),  # 1 NA
                    column4 = c(1, 2, 13, 4))    # NO NA


 # relative frequency of NA values
 missing_values <- colMeans(is.na(data))

 # What I want:

 column4,  column3, column2, column1
```

Comment: `data[order(missing_values)]`?

Comment: You could also modify your data *by reference* (without using `<-`) using `data.table::setcolorder(data, order(missing_values))` then check your `data`.